# label is not visible in UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am attempting to set a label into a subclassed UIToolBar.  I am first creating the label, then converting it to a UIBarButtonItem and setting them to the toolbar, but the toolbar just appears blank.

here is my code in my init method of my subclassed toolbar

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// prep the total label
_totalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_totalLabel.font = [_totalLabel.font fontWithSize:15];
_totalLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_totalLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"TOTAL", nil);
_totalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
_totalLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
_totalLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
_totalLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
_totalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[items addObject:spacer2];

UIBarButtonItem *total = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_totalLabel];
[items addObject:total];

[self setItems:items];
```

any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling this code from? If you have it in `initWithFrame:` or `initWithCoder:` it will not work.

Try this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    if(self.items.count == 0) {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

That will get it working. The question is though should you be doing this in `layoutSubviews`? Probably not. You could also put a setup method on your `UIToolbar` and call that at a later point in your application.

Comment: kinda sorta.  My init method calls [self setLabels] and the above code is in that method

Comment: You are going to have to do this work later on in the view's lifecycle. The subviews etc are not setup at the the init method is called. Call your setupLables method on the toolbar from viewDidLoad: in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a uitoolbar. this is a navigation bar so please remove navigationbar and add toolbar . Try this type .